# End of file issue. How to make sure it read the last lines AWK

Tags: awk

Basically my code goes through the whole file then doesn't print out the last two lines as there is nothing to keep it going when it can't find another 'P'
This is my code:

```
BEGIN{

FS= "|"
countA=CountB=0;

}

{

id=substr($2,1,1);
++file[id]




if ($3 == "P"){
#      print "message 1", countB, countA;

  if(countB==0){
    for(dupes in B){
      print B[dupes] > "Bdupes.txt"

      print dupesB[dupes];
      print "ouputted logs for B";
      }
    }

  else if(countA==0){
    for(dupes in A){
      print A[dupes] > "Adupes.txt"
      }
    }

  else if(countA==countB){
    i=1
    while(i<countA){

      print A[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      print B[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      i++;
      }
    }
  else if(countA<countB && countA!=0){

    i=1
    while(i<(countA+1)){
      print A[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      print B[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      i++;
      }



    i=countA+1
    while(i<(countB+1)){
      print B[i] > "Bdupes.txt"
      i++;
      }
    }
  else if(countB<countA && countB!=0){
    i=1
    k=countB + 1;
    while(i<k){
      print A[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      print B[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
      i++;
      }

    j=countB+1

    while(j<(countA+1)){
      print A[j] > "Adupes.txt"
      j++;
      }
    }


  if(id == "A"){
    A[1]=$0
    countA=1;
    countB=0;

    }

  else if (id == "B"){
    B[1]=$0
    countA=0;
    countB=1;
    }



  }
else if($3 == "C"){

  if(id=="A"){
    countA++;
    A[countA]=$0
    }

  else if(id == "B"){
    countB++;
    B[countB]=$0
    }
  }

else if($3 == "U"){

  print $0 > id "unique.txt";
  }

}



END{



for (file_id in file)
print file_id ":", file[file_id]

}
```

This is my file:

```
Name|ID|DDStatus|ParentID
Jon|A4|U|
Bob|B5|U|
Phil|A5|P|
Phil|B4|C|A5
Amy|A1|P|
Amy|A2|C|A1
Amy|B1|C|A1
Gareth|A3|P|
Gareth|B2|C|A3
Gareth|B3|C|A3
Elaine|B6|P|
Elaine|B7|C|B6
```

So my code misses out the last two so:

```
 Elaine|B6|P|
 Elaine|B7|C|B6
```

As it cannot find another 'P' after this. Is there anyway I can make sure it goes right to the end maybe something after my END procedure?
I want 5 files.

- One that shows the unique lines from file A. (you can tell its
  from file A/B from the beginning of the ID field.
- One that shows the unique lines from file B
- Parents & Children from A plus B (P & C)
- Parent & Dupes if both from file A or just the dupes if its AAB
- Parent & Dupes if both from file B or just the dupes if its ABB

So my Bdupes file is missing the two Elaines as the code is not processing the last two lines.

Bdupes:

```
Gareth|B3|C|A3
```

When it should be this:

```
Gareth|B3|C|A3
Elaine|B6|P|
Elaine|B7|C|B6
```

My code basically find the first record that is a parent P, but when it comes to the end of the file it doesn't carry on as there are no 'P's' left. Thats why the two Elaines are missing.

I now need to know how I can get AWK to process the last two lines?

TIA

Comment: TL;DR — well, not quite, but that code is very long and not appealingly laid out, and there is no explanation of what the logic is supposed to be doing, so it is hard to tell what it is doing wrong.  To get an answer, you have to ask an answerable question, which means, in part, explaining what you are trying to achieve — if only to avoid the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Please review how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: what output do you get? what output do you want?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope I have made it clearer? TIA Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it could be greatly simplified.  If you want to avoid doing that refactoring, one simple solution is to append spare input.  For example, you might get away with simply changing `if( $3 == "P" )` to `if ($3 == "P" || NR != FNR )` and running awk on a second file in which the input is mostly ignored.  (Depending on the logic, it's not clear if you may have to cook up reasonable input or add more logic to terminate cleanly, and the code is too ugly to determine that without paying attention.)  This is effectively (nearly) the same as wrapping that code block in an END block.  Another nice option is to use a user-defined function and call it when you see a 'P' line and from the END block.

Either way, your first step is to refactor your code.